# Angular 2 http post adds quotes around json object

Tags: angular

I'm trying to make a http post in angular 2 below is the code snippet. HTTP post adds quotes " " around the json object and hence the call fails. How can I remove those quotes from my request?

```
export class Compentency {
  competencies : number[];
}
postData() {
        let array =  [1, 2, 3, 6];
        this.comp.competencies = array;
        let  headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, method: 'post' });
        return this.http.post(this.postUrl, this.comp, options)
        .map(res => res.json().data.competencies)
        .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

below is the form data passed to server

```
{
"competencies": [ 1, 2, 3, 6 ]
}:
```

Comment: I did stringify for the data. this still adds a quotes around form data {"competencies":[1,2,3,6]}: my server dose not accept quotes for key.

Answer (score 1):

I had to change the headers content type to application/json and it works now.